# Confusion in using log.retention.bytes parameter in logging Topic data in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

"log.retention.bytes" is the parameter we are using to retain the logs of topic messages and I had given value as 1073741824.

I had referred the Kafka documentation, where it says the size given in "log.retention.bytes" is per partition, so that means suppose if I have 20 partitions for all the topics I am using, then total size of bytes that Kafka will retain is 20*1073741824 according to the documentation.

But what clarity I need is

```
Will Kafka retain 20*1073741824 bytes for all the topics?
                     (or)
Will Kafka retain 20*1073741824 bytes per topic?
```

Answer (score 5):

**log.retention.bytes** Parameter used to retain in the log for each topic partition. By default, log size is unlimited.

This configuration controls the maximum size a partition (which consists of log segments) can grow to before we will discard old log segments to free up space if we are using the **"delete" retention** policy. **By default there is no size limit only a time limit. Since this limit is enforced at the partition level, multiply it by the number of partitions to compute the topic retention in bytes.**

If you set **log.retention.bytes = 1 GB**, Kafka will **trigger a clean-up activity** when the partition size reaches to 1 GB. **Remember that it is not a topic size. It is partition size.**

Kafka give you other option to configure the retention periond i.e **log.retention.ms**.. The default retention period is seven days.If you want to change the duration, you can specify your value for log.retention.ms configuration.

If you specify both configurations, the clean-up will start on meeting either of the criteria.

Comment: @B Rajshekar Reddy.. Does my comment answer to your question?

Comment: Note: Retention bytes is also a lower bound of when the log cleaner will **start**. It is not a "limit" of the topic/partition size