# Could we control the topic maximum size (not the message size in the topic) by any way?

Tags: apache-kafka

In our environment, our cluster is shared with multiple applications and one of the application team loading the data unexpectedly with out any notofication and due to that all disk are full and impacting other application too.

To avoid this problem, like In RDBMS MSSQL or Oracle, is there any way to restrict that application topic size not exceed more than some quota which we allocated as a max value for that topic.

in this way, other applications will not impact. Much appreciated your inputs here.

for e.g, my disk capacity is 1 TB and around 6 application topics on this cluster. i want to restrict the max topic size of the highly load topic to some 500GB. Kindly advise please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confusion in using log.retention.bytes parameter in logging Topic data in Apache Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55374890/confusion-in-using-log-retention-bytes-parameter-in-logging-topic-data-in-apache)

Comment: Quotas are only for network, not storage https://docs.confluent.io/kafka/design/quotas.html#quota-configuration

Comment: We are more Worried about the Disk storage only and our Kafka clusters will be down due to 100% disk full due to one of the application team data. we want to control that team by setting the max disk usage to that topic up to 50% of the total disk capacity.